# Have RecyclerView children match parent height when using constructor instead of inflate to create them

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to have a RecyclerView with custom child views (`CustomView`). The custom child view has some limited view logics in it, which is why I don't want to inflate it inside the ViewHolder as a `View`, but rather construct it as a dedicated view (`CustomView`).

I declared my `CustomView`'s layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
<!-- ... -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The constructor for `CustomView` looks like this:

```
inflate(context, R.layout.layout_custom_view, this)
```

`onCreateViewHolder` then constructs the view:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
            val view = CustomView(parent!!.context)
            val viewHolder = ...
            return viewHolder
}
```

That works fine in general. However, my `CustomView` is supposed to match the RecylerView's height and width, but just gets as big as it just needs to be to render.

**How can I have `CustomView` actually match the RecyclerView's height and width?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out the solution is simple when you think about it. Simply adding

```
view.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

after constructing the view solved the issue.